# IntelliJ - working with features

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have 2 simple questions that I cannot find answer to.

First is in [NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqkxc.png) when I type . operator behind a variable or method or whatever, small window with documentation will show up like on the  picture. On the other hand I can't achieve the same result in IntelliJ. I followed steps on official website and this is what I get in [IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0054r.png) after I press CTRL+Q. All I want is full documentation so for a begginer like me it would be easier to use and learn stuff.

[EDIT]: I tried it once again and I saw little yellow message "download missing driver" and it is working just fine.. this one is solved.
Second question is about MySQL database driver (or connector). In NetBeans, I just press right click on project and add the library I want. But I can't find solution for this in IntelliJ.

Thanks for every advice!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I'm thinking what you mean is the suggestions after you type a '.'. In IntelliJ, the suggestions show only if you have config a right dependency in the **File > Project Structure**, and the **Libraries** tab.

And for the second question, also you should find **File > Project Structure**, in the **Modules** tab, Add new Database support(Hibernate such as) for you project.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have 1.8(java version "1.8.0_91") in dependency. But the thing is, I want that text you put in documentation.. that is what I don't get. Look at the pictures, in netbeans I have full documentation for every method. On IntelliJ picture I don't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally found the solution.

I went to **Project Structure** -> **SDKs** -> **Documentation Paths** and I added https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ in there so now when I press CTRL+Q for quick documentation it shows exactly what I needed.